# Pull request a diff

Tags: git, github

I would like to create a pull request for a diff between two commits (a parent and it's child). I can do a diff beetween my two commits with `d4242...d4141`, but it seams that github don't allow to put `d4242...d4141` in the  field.
(Error : There isn't anything to compare.)

Are they a way to pull request a diff, or at least to tell to remove some files/hash from a diff between the original repository and the fork repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only create pull requests for branches, so just create a branch that points to `d4141` and start a pull request for that one.

You should also make sure that the whole branch is rebased on top of the upstream’s master and that it does *not* contain any further dependencies you might have in your own repository. So it should not look like this:

```
  A --- B --- C --- [d4242] --- * --- * --- [d4141]
 /
X --- * --- * --- [upstream/master]
```

If that is the case, you should get rid of commits `A`, `B` and `C` because they are unique to your fork. You can do that by creating a new branch off either `X` or `upstream/master` and then cherry-picking all the commits you want in your pull request:

```
git checkout -b new-pull-request upstream/master
git cherry-pick d4242..d4141
git push origin new-pull-request
```

Then you can create your pull request for that branch.

In general, stuff you do for an upstream project which you want to contribute to should be done in separate topic branches, i.e. branches that are completely independent and separated. This way you will never run into problems where you have dependency issues from commits that might not make it into the upstream repository. It also makes it a lot easier for the maintainer of the upstream repository to accept your pull requests.

Comment: I cleaned the repository and applied each patch in a separated branch, as you said. This way it's both simple for me and for the maintainers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you could start a new branch based on upstream and cherry-pick `d4141` on that and do a pull request for the new branch.